# Why is the attribute called [Serializable] and not [SerializableAttribute] (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

There is a hole in my understanding around .NET attributes. The class definition for the Serializable class is this:

```
namespace System {
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Delegate, Inherited = false)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public sealed class SerializableAttribute : Attribute {
        public SerializableAttribute();
    }
}
```

Why though when you use it is it called [Serializable] and not [SerializableAttribute]? Although you appear to be able to use the later.

Is there some kind of aliasing going on here? This is going to be a "doh!" moment I suspect...

Comment: Thank - it is a duplicate question. I'd searched on attribute alias not abbreviation. Often half the problem is knowing what to search on when you don't know the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# language specification allows the compiler to infer to the 'Attribute' part of the type name. As @Jim explains in the comment, you can explicitly include the 'Attribute' part of the type name, but it's not necessary. Both usages are semantically equivalent.

The MSDN article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) goes into further detail under the 'Using an Attribute Class' section. Last but not least, the actual [citation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664612(v=vs.71).aspx) of the section in the C# language specification that allows this behavior:

> By convention, attribute classes are named with a suffix of Attribute. Uses of an attribute may either include or omit this suffix.

Comment: Yes, correct. And if you like, you can still add "Attribute" to if you like, but it is considered redundant, thus the aliasing.